# Magento 2 rest api Information

Tags: magento2, rest-api, wishlist

i am trying to get wishlistdata using api

where i can find these

```
header "Authorization: Bearer pbhercbtk6dd3eatf1pyx8jj45avjluu"
```

Actual query

```
$ curl -X GET http://magento.example.com/rest/V1/wishlist --header "Authorization: Bearer pbhercbtk6dd3eatf1pyx8jj45avjluu"
```

Any thoughts on this ?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please specify the exact problem you are facing ?